# Junction object field has weird name in WSDL

Tags: soql, custom-field, wsdl, junction-object

Lets say i have objects Event and Contact. Between these two objects i have created junction object. Checking WSDL whats the name of field on Event for this junction reference I find out, that it is referenced like this:

```
<element name="R00N30000001WZmFEAW__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
```

Can somebody explain how could that happen? Will be this field named same in other sandboxes?

Comment: Is this a field you created? I only saw this for installed package fields that are lookups

Comment: i dont think so, but im no sure... im working with existing org....it doesnt have namespace

Comment: Is this the Partner or Enterprise WSDL? The name appears to be an "R" prefix, then the [Custom Field ID](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#00N), then the "__r" suffix for a reference.